# What Password is needed to run Xcode?

Tags: macos, password, user-account

I just downloaded the Xcode application again after a few months, but it asks me for a password that I do not have. No "password forgotten", I do not know how to proceed to open the application?

Comment: This site is English Language only. I've used Google Translate to quickly add an English translation. Please check it is what you actually intended.

Answer (score 1):

Open system preferences and see if you can unlock a pane selecting the lock.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203127

That password is the one for admin access and it’s the same password needed for Xcode to install additional components and get admin control to debug and package files.